# Leaflet Maps: How to create an overlay with key/value pairs using the contents from an array?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

In my project, when I load a page I pull a list of overlay names from the database, these are stored in a JS Array.

Using the default code below, how do I fill the overlayMaps with contents from an array rather than hard coding what the values will be:

```
 var overlayMaps = {
"Cities": cities,
"Towns": towns
};
```

So as an example, instead of creating overlayMaps with the hard coded values Cities & Towns, I need to pull these values from an array that gets its data from the DB, The array in leymans terms might look like this under the hood:

```
[ "MyValue1": myvalue1,"MyValue2": myvalue2, "MyValue2": myvalue2,] etc
```

Maybe I need to create a dictionary, although I have no experience doing this in JS, only in C#

Am using guide: https://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control/

Comment: Are you saying you want overlayMaps to be an object where the key is whatever is at "MyValue1" and the value is whatever myvalue1 is?

Comment: Hi. In the example code above, var overlayMaps has hard coded values, instead i need to populate the contents of the var overlayMaps with values that I pull from an array. The array is dynamically populated with strings from a DB table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

Reading the leaflet API instructions, you can actually add a single item to an L.control
one at a time using the command addOverlay( layer,  name). Adds an overlay (checkbox entry) with the given name to the control. For demo purposes below, I'm using the same value var cities for each of the three checkboxes, but to show how we add the individual items from the array, we're looping through this array and adding the items one at a time.

```
 var littleton = L.marker([39.61, -105.02]).bindPopup('This is Littleton, CO.'),
    denver = L.marker([39.74, -104.99]).bindPopup('This is Denver, CO.'),
    aurora = L.marker([39.73, -104.8]).bindPopup('This is Aurora, CO.'),
    golden = L.marker([39.77, -105.23]).bindPopup('This is Golden, CO.');

 var cities = L.layerGroup([littleton, denver, aurora, golden]);
```

```
var places = new Array()
places.push("Cities");
places.push("Towns");
places.push("MyPlaces");

var lControl = L.control.layers(null, null);
lControl.addTo(map);

places.forEach(myFunction);

function myFunction (item) {
    lControl.addOverlay(cities, '' + item + '');
}
```

[image: Images]

Comment: if the number of points to be marked on the map is huge it might take a long time to render the map. I guess leaflet marker cluster would be a better way to handle this situation. [link](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster)

Comment: Yes the solution used will depend partly on the numbers and what you're wanting to achieve, for me this is only a small part of the process as each marker will be a custom design, along with a user configured custom form inside the popup. All these details will have to be pulled from the database. In my environment, i'm not planning on using hundreds of markers but more having markers with lots of functionality.